# Como faço para mostra o nome do usuário logado em minha pagina de cadastrado?

Tags: php, html, mysql

Boa tarde, gostaria de exibir o nome do usuário logado em minha página de cadastro, tentei de diversas formas, porem nenhuma destas formas houve exito, gostaria que me ajudassem a resolver esse problema.

**BANCO DE DADOS**

```
CREATE DATABASE bdBrunSker;

USE bdBrunSker;

CREATE TABLE Usuario (
    nomeCompleto    VARCHAR (100) NOT NULL,
    apelido         VARCHAR (100) NOT NULL,
    cpf             VARCHAR (50)  NOT NULl,
    sexo            VARCHAR (9)   NOT NULL,
    nascimento      VARCHAR     (20)  NOT NULL,
    estado          VARCHAR (50)      NOT NULL,
    email           VARCHAR (100) NOT NULL,
    cidade          VARCHAR (50)  NOT NULL,
    cep             VARCHAR (50)  NOT NULL,
    telefone        VARCHAR (20)  NOT NULL,
    celular         VARCHAR    (20)  NOT NULL,
    usuario         VARCHAR (100) NOT NULL,
    senha           VARCHAR (100) NOT NULL,
    arquivo         VARCHAR (220) NULL
    );




SELECT * FROM Usuario;
```

**INFORMAÇÕES DO LOGIN**

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$db_name = "bdBrunSker";

$connect = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $db_name);

$usuario = $_POST["usuario"];
$senha = $_POST["senha"];


$sql = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT nomeCompleto, arquivo FROM usuarios WHERE senha = '$usuario' AND senha = '$senha'");
$bd = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql);

if (!empty($bd)) {
    $_SESSION["nomeCompleto"]  = $bd["nomeCompleto"];
    $_SESSION["arquivo"]    = $bd["arquivo"];
}

if(mysqli_connect_error()):
    echo "Falha na conexão: ".mysqli_connect_error();
endif;


if(isset($_POST['enviar'])):
    $erros = array();
    $usuario = mysqli_escape_string($connect, $_POST['usuario']);
    $senha = mysqli_escape_string($connect, $_POST['senha']);

    if(empty($usuario) or empty($senha)):
      $erros[] = "<li style ='padding-top: 15px;'> O Campo usuario/senha precisa ser preenchido! </li>";  
    else:
        $sql = "SELECT usuario, senha FROM Usuario WHERE usuario = '$usuario' AND senha = '$senha'";
        $resultado = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);

            if(mysqli_num_rows($resultado) == 1):
                $dados = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado);
                header('Location: selecionarUsuario.php');
            else:
                $erros[] = "<li style ='padding-top: 15px;'> Usuário e senha não conferem! </li>";
            endif;

        if(mysqli_num_rows($resultado) > 0):

            $sql = "SELECT * FROM Usuario WHERE usuario = '$usuario' AND senha = '$senha'";
            $resultado = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);

        else:
            $erros[] = "<li style ='padding-top: 15px;'> Usuário inexistente! </li>";
        endif;
    endif;
endif;
```

**PÁGINA PARA EXIBIR O NOME DO USUÁRIO LOGADO**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<title>BrunSker Tecnologia - Cadastro</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<!--Adaptação para mobile-->
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=0.55, user-scalable=0">
<!--Ícone do site-->
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="resources/icoBrunSker.ico">
<!--Ícones do fontawesome-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css">
<!--Ícone do site-->
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="resources/icoBrunSker.ico">
<!--Ícones do fontawesome-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css">
<!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- Material Design Bootstrap -->
<link href="css/mdb.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- Style page -->
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!--Font Montserrat-->
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<!--Jquery-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<!--Alertifyjs-->
<script src="alertifyjs/alertify.min.js"></script>
<!--JQuery Mask-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mask.min.js"></script>
<!--Mascaras-->
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#cpf").mask("000.000.000-00")
    $("#cnpj").mask("00.000.000/0000-00")
    $("#telefone").mask("(00) 0000-0000")
    $("#salario").mask("999.999.990,00", {
        reverse: true
    })
    $("#cep").mask("00.000-000")
    $("#dataNascimento").mask("00/00/0000")

    $("#rg").mask("999.999.999-W", {
        translation: {
            'W': {
                pattern: /[X0-9]/
            }
        },
        reverse: true
    })

    var options = {
        translation: {
            'A': {
                pattern: /[A-Z]/
            },
            'a': {
                pattern: /[a-zA-Z]/
            },
            'S': {
                pattern: /[a-zA-Z0-9]/
            },
            'L': {
                pattern: /[a-z]/
            },
        }
    }

    $("#placa").mask("AAA-0000", options)

    $("#codigo").mask("AA.LLL.0000", options)

    $("#celular").mask("(00) 00000-0000")

    $("#celular").blur(function(event) {
        if ($(this).val().length == 15) {
            $("#celular").mask("(00) 00000-0009")
        } else {
            $("#celular").mask("(00) 0000-00009")
        }
    })
})
</script>

<body>

    <nav class="mb-1 navbar scrolling-navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark lighten-1">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="resources/brunSkerLogo.png" class="brunSkerLogo"></a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent-555"
            aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent-555" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent-555">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto nav-flex-icons">
                <form class="form-inline" method="POST" action="pesquisar.php">
                    <div class="md-form my-0">
                        <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" name="pesquisar" placeholder="Buscar usuário"
                            aria-label="Search">
                    </div>
                    <button class="btn btn-outline-white btn-md my-2 my-sm-0 ml-3" type="submit"><i
                            class="fas fa-search"></i></button>
                </form>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link btMaisCad" href="selecionarUsuario.php"><i class="fas fa-clipboard-list"></i>
                        Listagem<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown"> 
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink-333" data-toggle="dropdown"
                        aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><?php $usuario ?>
                        <img src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Avatars/avatar-5.jpg"
                            class="rounded-circle z-depth-0" alt="avatar image" height="35">
                    </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right dropdown-default"
                        aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink-333">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="index.php">Sair</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="container containerCadastro" id="inserirUsuario">
        <div class="cadastroSize z-depth-4 rounded mb-0">
            <h2 class="titulo text-center">Cadastrar</h2>
            <hr />
            <div class="formulario quadroCadastro">
                <form method="post" action="salvaUsuario.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <div class="input-group-prepend">
                            <span class="input-group-text" id="inputGroupFileAddon01">Perfil</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="custom-file">
                            <input type="file" name="arquivo" required class="custom-file-input" id="inputGroupFile01"
                                aria-describedby="inputGroupFileAddon01" accept="image/png, image/jpeg">
                            <label class="custom-file-label" for="inputGroupFile01">Escolha uma foto para o seu perfil</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="md-form">
                        <i class="fas fa-signature prefix iconColor shadowIcon"></i>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control iptNomeCompleto" id="iptNomeCompleto" name="nomeCompleto"
                            spellcheck="false" required="required" data-error="Informe o seu nome completo!"
                            placeholder="Nome completo">
                        <div class="help-block with-errors" required title="Informe o seu nome completo!"></div>
                        <label for="lblNomeCompleto"></label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="md-form">
                        <i class="fas fa-mask prefix iconColor shadowIcon"></i>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control iptApelido" id="iptApelido" name="apelido"
                            spellcheck="false" required="required" data-error="Informe o seu apelido!"
                            placeholder="Apelido">
                        <div class="help-block with-errors" required title="Informe o seu apelido!"></div>
                        <label for="lblApelido"></label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="md-form">
                        <i class="fas fa-id-card prefix iconColor shadowIcon"></i>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control iptCpf" id="cpf" name="cpf" spellcheck="false"
                            required="required" data-error="Informe o seu CPF!" placeholder="CPF">
                        <div class="help-block with-errors" required title="Informe o seu CPF!"></div>
                        <label for="lblCpf"></label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group mb-form">
                        <i class="fas fa-venus-mars prefix iconColor genderIcon shadowIcon"></i>
                        <select class="custom-select rounded-pill" id="sexo" name="sexo">
                            <option selected>Sexo</option>
                            <option value="Masculino">Masculino</option>
                            <option value="Feminino">Feminino</option>
                            <option value="Outro">Outro</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="md-form">
                        <i class="fas fa-birthday-cake prefix iconColor shadowIcon"></i>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control iptNascimento" id="dataNascimento" name="nascimento"
                            spellcheck="false" required="required" data-error="Informe data do seu nascimento!"
                            placeholder="Data de nascimento">
                        <div class="help-block with-errors" required title="Informe a sua data de nascimento!"></div>
                        <label for="lblNascimento"></label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="md-form">
                        <i class="fas fa-flag prefix iconColor shadowIcon"></i>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control iptNascimento" id="estado" name="estado"
                            spellcheck="false" required="required" data-error="Informe o seu estado!"
                            placeholder="Estado">
                        <div class="help-block with-errors" required title="Informe o seu estado!"></div>
                        <label for="lblEstado"></label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="md-form">
                        <i class="fas fa-envelope prefix iconColor shadowIcon"></i>
                        <input type="email" class="form-control iptEmail" id="email" name="email" spellcheck="false"
                            required="required" data-error="Informe o seu e-mail!" placeholder="E-mail">
                        <div class="help-block with-errors" required title="Informe o seu e-mail!"></div>
                        <label for="lblEmail"></label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="md-form">
                        <i class="fas fa-city prefix iconColor shadowIcon"></i>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control iptCidade" id="cidade" name="cidade" spellcheck="false"
                            required="required" data-error="Informe a sua cidade!" placeholder="Cidade">
                        <div class="help-block with-errors" required title="Informe a sua cidade!"></div>
                        <label for="lblCidade"></label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="md-form">
                        <i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt prefix iconColor shadowIcon"></i>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control iptCep" id="cep" name="cep" spellcheck="false"
                            required="required" data-error="Informe o seu CEP!" placeholder="CEP">
                        <div class="help-block with-errors" required title="Informe o seu CEP!"></div>
                        <label for="lblCep"></label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="md-form">
                        <i class="fas fa-phone prefix iconColor shadowIcon"></i>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control iptTelefone" id="telefone" name="telefone"
                            spellcheck="false" required="required" data-error="Informe o seu telefone!"
                            placeholder="Telefone">
                        <div class="help-block with-errors" required title="Informe o seu telefone!"></div>
                        <label for="lblTelefone"></label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="md-form">
                        <i class="fas fa-mobile-alt prefix iconColor shadowIcon"></i>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control iptCelular" id="celular" name="celular"
                            spellcheck="false" required="required" data-error="Informe o seu celular!"
                            placeholder="Celular">
                        <div class="help-block with-errors" required title="Informe o seu celular!"></div>
                        <label for="lblCelular"></label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="md-form">
                        <i class="fas fa-user-circle prefix iconColor shadowIcon"></i>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control iptUsuario" id="usuario" name="usuario"
                            spellcheck="false" required="required" data-error="Informe o seu usuario!"
                            placeholder="Usuário">
                        <div class="help-block with-errors" required title="Informe o seu usuário!"></div>
                        <label for="lblUsuario"></label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="md-form">
                        <i class="fas fa-key prefix iconColor shadowIcon"></i>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control iptSenha" id="senha" name="senha" spellcheck="false"
                            required="required" data-error="Informe a sua senha!" placeholder="Senha">
                        <div class="help-block with-errors" required title="Informe a sua senha!"></div>
                        <label for="lblSenha"></label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary rounded-pill botaoEntrar" id='botao' name="enviar">
                            <i class="fas fa-sign-in-alt icoButton"></i>Inserir</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="container">
        </div>
    </div>




    <!-- Image of location/map -->

    <!-- Footer -->
    <footer class="page-footer font-small darken-3">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12 py-5">
                    <div class="mb-5 flex-center"> <a class="fb-ic"
                            href="https://www.facebook.com/pg/BrunSker/posts/?ref=page_internal" target="_blank"> <i
                                class="fab fa-facebook-f fa-lg white-text mr-md-5 mr-3 fa-2x"> </i> </a>
                        <a class="tw-ic"
                            href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/brunsker-tecnologia/?originalSubdomain=br"
                            target="_blank"> <i class="fab fa-linkedin fa-lg white-text mr-md-5 mr-3 fa-2x"> </i> </a>
                        <a class="ins-ic" href="https://www.instagram.com/brunsker/?hl=pt-br" target="_blank"> <i
                                class="fab fa-instagram fa-lg white-text mr-md-5 mr-3 fa-2x"> </i> </a> </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="footer-copyright py-3">© 2020 BrunSker Tecnologia.</div>
    </footer>
    <!-- Bootstrap tooltips -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/popper.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- MDB core JavaScript -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/mdb.min.js"></script>
    <!--Style.js-->
    <script type="text/javascript " src="js/style.js "></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Gostaria de exibir o nome do usuário na linha 107, onde esta escrito  "$usuario"!

Answer (score 0):

Coloque no local onde você quer o nome do usuário:

```
<?=$_SESSION["nomeCompleto"];?>
```

ou

```
<?php echo $_SESSION["nomeCompleto"];?>
```